# Hough Transform in matlab to display lines

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I wanted to use Hough Transform on my images.

```
I=imread('myimage.png');
I=im2bw(I);
BW = bwmorph(I,'skel',1);
[H, T, R] = hough(BW)
P = houghpeaks(H, 100);
lines = houghlines(BW, T, R, P, 'FillGap',5, 'MinLength', 20);
```

Now I want to print all the lines in separate image files(each line on separate image).How can I do it?

**Edit**- I do not want the orignial image in the background and draw lines over that original image.I want to have a new image with just one line per image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [findobj](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findobj.html) to fetch lines on the current axes and delete them one at a time right before plotting the next line. Right after that capture the content of the axes using [getframe](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getframe.html?searchHighlight=getframe) and save it with `imwrite`.

For the following example I used the `circuit.tif` demo image and applied a Canny edge to highlight lines, but this should work for your application.

```
clear
clc
close all

I=imread('circuit.tif');
%BW = bwmorph(I,'skel',1);
BW = edge(I,'canny');

[H, T, R] = hough(BW);
P = houghpeaks(H, 100);
lines = houghlines(BW, T, R, P, 'FillGap',5, 'MinLength', 20);

%// NEW \\
imshow(true(size(BW)));

hold on
for k = 1:numel(lines)

    %// Delete current line displayed
   CurrLine = findobj('Type','line');
   delete(CurrLine);

   %// Plot current line
   xy = [lines(k).point1; lines(k).point2];
   plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','green');

   drawnow

   %// Create file name and capture axes content
   CurrentFrame = getframe(gca);

   ImageName = sprintf('Image_%i',k);

   %// Save image
   imwrite(CurrentFrame.cdata,[ImageName '.jpg'],'jpg');

end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: No,actually I dont want the original image in the background.i just want the image with one line per image.

Comment: ok so let's say a green line (or whatever color) over a white background?

Comment: Yes but the location and length of that line should be the same as the original line it represents

Comment: you're most welcome! I corrected a typo in the loop; before the counter was set to `for k = numel(lines)` but that should be `for k = 1:numel(lines)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `insertShape` function from the Computer Vision System Toolbox to draw the lines into an image.